# System Preferences lock always unlocks itself after restart

Tags: macos, system-settings, unlock, restart, administrator

The Mac's System Preferences panels have a universal "lock" icon which, when locked, will apply to all panes, therefore preventing the user from changing any settings until they unlock the System Preferences by typing in their admin password.

I like to keep it locked at all times. However, whenever I restart my computer, System Preferences unlocks itself.

How do I keep the lock setting locked even after a restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to ***Security & Privacy***, then ***Advanced***.

check the box for ***Require an administrator password to access locked preferences***

That should ensure all the lockable prefs default to locked.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. If it survives a restart, then I'll mark this as Answered.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had to do a restart to check first because I've had other System Preferences problems before and thought that this problem might be related to those problems rather than this checkbox. But in this case, the checkbox did the trick.