# How can I disable password for system preferences lock? How can I permanently unlock all system preferences?

Tags: macos, system-settings

Is there any way to disable the "Click the lock to make changes" needing a password, or is there a way to permanently unlock all settings in Mountain Lion?

More specifically I'm turning the Network Link Conditioner  ( to simulate slow connections ) on and off frequently from its system preferences pane and it needs a password each time and it's getting annoying.

I'm comfortable with the security issues this presents if I could revert to the default behavior at some point.

**Edit**

I'd just like to point out that in the time it takes to think up a sarcastic reply to an answer ( *but ultimately not send because you're too polite* ), the lock locks itself automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The settings stay unlocked, just do not click the "lock". This will keep the stuff unlocked until you want to lock it again.

Comment: Thanks, is there any **other** way to keep it unlocked if the lock locks itself after a minute?

Comment: This is clearly how it is designed (and it is a good design), but for many users like me, it does not work. The padlock is re-locked each time that System Preferences is reopened.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse version of the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/85131/180568) on how to enable the lock:

Go to **Security & Privacy**, then **Advanced**.

uncheck the box for **Require an administrator password to access system-wide preferences**

That should ensure all the lockable prefs default to unlocked.

Comment: That is not the purpose of that check box which is exactly what you have said, not what the OP wants.